# Removing the white space at the start of each variable IN A LIST

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove the space that at the start of each variable but not the spaces after that.

I have a list like this:

```
input= structure(list(X = 2:4, V1 = c(NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(" Tescho123C", 
" Tescho123A", " Tescho123B"), V3 = c(" Instrument", " Instrument", 
" Instrument"), V4 = c(" :Fanta", " :Fanta", " :Fanta"), V5 = c(" :Tool Time", 
" :Tool Time", " :Tool Time")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

And I'm trying to get something like this

```
output = structure(list(X = 2:4, V1 = c(NA, NA, NA), V2 = c("Tescho123C", 
"Tescho123A", "Tescho123B"), V3 = c("Instrument", "Instrument", 
"Instrument"), V4 = c(":Fanta", ":Fanta", ":Fanta"), V5 = c(":Tool Time", 
":Tool Time", ":Tool Time")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Everything I've tried seems to be more complex than it should be and takes a long time to run.

NB: trimws does not work on list - only vectors - and I'd prefer for to have to change my input.

Can anyone suggest an elegant solution?

Comment: how about `sapply(input, trimws)`?

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen that is exactly what I mean.  i must be tired, my brain isn't working.  if you want to "answer" the question, i'm mark it correct.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sapply(input, trimws)
```

Mind however that the result is a matrix, and trimws tunrs everything to character.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
input %>% mutate(across(starts_with('V'), ~ str_remove(., '^\\s')))
  X   V1         V2         V3     V4         V5
1 2 <NA> Tescho123C Instrument :Fanta :Tool Time
2 3 <NA> Tescho123A Instrument :Fanta :Tool Time
3 4 <NA> Tescho123B Instrument :Fanta :Tool Time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::map` and `stringr::str_trim`, like this:

```
map(input, ~str_trim(., side = "left"))
```

**EDIT**
If you want to ignore non-character elements, and so preserve their type, use `map_if`:

```
map_if(input, is.character, ~ str_trim(.x, side = "left"))
```